# How to use react-native-image-carousel library with flatlist

Tags: image, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am using react-native-image-carousel library for showing my image gallery i want images should slide after opening.

While i am using same example of static data its working. here it is example https://github.com/anvilabs/react-native-image-carousel/blob/master/Example/App.js. but i am using flatlist to dislpay my images and i getting error while trying to use with flatlist.

this is my render image function

```
    renderImage = (idx) => (
    <Image
      style={StyleSheet.absoluteFill}
      resizeMode="contain"
      source={{ uri: this.state.gallery[idx] }}
    />
  );
```

and this is my flatlist

```
<View>
        <FlatList
          numColumns={3}
          data={this.state.gallery}
          keyExtractor={(i) => i}
          renderItem={({ item }) =>
            <ImageCarousel
            ref={(imageCarousel) => {
              this._imageCarousel = imageCarousel;
            }}
              renderContent={this.renderImage}>

              <View style={styles.galleryStyle}>
                <Image style={styles.imageStyle1} source={{ uri: item.image }} />
              </View>

            </ImageCarousel>
          }
        ></FlatList>
      </View>
```

if i am running this code i am getting error like `error while updating property src of a view value of uri can't be cast from readableNativeMap to string`

and my gallery state contain

```
(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {project: 2, image: "http://media/projects/gallery_image/homepage-banner.jpg"}
1: {project: 2, image: "http://media/project/software-development.jpg"}
2: {project: 2, image: "http://media/projects/gallery_image/New_FRS_Image_Mobile_app_development.jpg"}
length: 3
__proto__: Array(0)
```

and i have defined my state as

```
this.state={
gallery: {
        images: []
      }
}
```

please help if anyone know about it. Thanks in advace

Comment: please add answer if anyone have idea about it

Comment: I need an answer to this as well :( Did you ever figure it out?